# Can somebody identify these missing parts at the input stage of a Red Pitaya?

Tags: amplifier, buffer

The board is from Red Pitaya. The chip [AD8066](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8065_8066.pdf). It is being used as unity buffer. The components I have marked with black boxes are kept at input pins(3 and 5) of the chip.
[image]

Comment: looks like there are three components missing ... connections look odd .... perhaps inductors of some type

Comment: My guess was optional ESD protection diodes in a SC74 casing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange kind of "open source" that doesn't come with a schematic. They appear to be some kind of protection diode arrays as @Janka suggests (eg. TVS array). Here's what the 3D model looks like:

[image]

The other parts (two lead and apparently unpolarized) may be resistors.

Comment: from where did found this 3D model?

Comment: https://redpitaya.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developerGuide/125-14/mechSpec.html

Comment: what tool do u use to open them? Solidworks?

Comment: Solidworks will work or Altium should work.

Comment: I use Allegro 16.6V. I cant open step large step files

Comment: You can try this free site for viewing .stp format files: https://beta.sharecad.org/en/ up to 50M (this one is only 2M).

Answer (score 0):

There are two input impedance ratio divider options like a scope probe with RC ratios but at different ratios that 10:1 for a 2V or 40V range Vpp.

Your values are different.

[image]

These must be low pF ESD clamps (TVS arrays) for 1500 V ratings or more not included.

Perhaps the RC protection offers enough bypassing. If built like this with 50:1 reduction.

But without specs, or test results why guess?